Classroom response system / conference voting system
I am looking for a conference feedback / conference voting or classroom response system.
The system

should run on a Linux machine as the server
should provide a website for users to vote/participate
should work without registration or login, e.g. using a QR code which is presented on slides
should have PowerPoint integration for the results or provide a result website
is open-source, i.e. allows commercial use
is selfhosted, i.e. I can install it on my own server
may be a Docker container

It should have the options to

choose from predefined answers only (like a quiz)
allow arbitrary text input (like asking for opinions)

Ideally, it supports multiple languages. At least either English or German is required.
I have tried:

Slido is not self-hosted, but probably very close to what I need
Poll Everywhere is commercial only
Active Quiz is a Moodle plugin and I don't need all the Moodle stuff. It just makes things complicated.
eBalot is commercial
Mentimeter is commercial
Particify does not seem to be available for self-hosting and it's unclear to me what terms apply for businesses
arsnova does not seem to be supported any more and actually I see no code in that repository.
invote does not seem to be open-source
bli.do does not support polls.


Maybe Claper. Can anyone recommend it?

Maybe Pingo. Can anyone recommend it?

Maybe schnaq. Can anyone recommend it?
